# PCS and corosync/pacemaker

Tags: pacemaker, pcs, corosync

A simple and fast question about pcs.
With this command

```
pcs resource create NameService named op monitor interval=30s
```

I create a resource named,wich is working,but if i want to run `named -u named -t /var/chroot` instead of default named,how to create a resource with those options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the named resource agent a user via 'named_user', and you can pass other options via 'named_options':

`pcs resource create NameService named named_user=named \
     named_options="-t /var/chroot" op monitor interval=30s`

Or you could try using the "anything" resource agent to feed options to named. It would look something like this:

`pcs resource create NameService ocf:heartbeat:anything  \
     binfile="/usr/sbin/named" cmdline_options="-u named -t /var/chroot" \
     pidfile="/var/run/named.pid" op monitor interval=30s`

EDIT: 
For more resource agent options:

`# pcs resource describe ocf:heartbeat:named`

Comment: Thanks,also using the syntax systemd:heartbeat works,but thanks for answer

Comment: setting a resource to manage systemd:heartbeat will mean that Pacemaker will try to start/stop/monitor the heartbeat systemd unit, which you really wouldn't want to do :-P

Comment: Whoops,I meant systemd:named,i little error sorry